# Executed in Windows 10 like a charm but throw Exception on windows 7

Tags: c#, wpf

I have developed an app in windows 10 via Visual Studio 2015 and C# WPF, my app firmework target is 3.5 and
this app executes and debug without any Error in my system and get success.

But when I copy the app's file to windows 7 (another system) its getting crashed.

.Net 3.5 is installed on windows 7, below is the exception I am getting on windows 7

```
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: Cannot create instance of 'ucAtmsEditor' defined in assembly 'Amanager2, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.  Error at object 'System.Windows.Controls.TabItem' in markup file 'Amanager2;component/mainwindow.xaml' Line 29 Position 26. ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Amanager2.STATICS' threw an exception. ---> System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'applicationintent'.

   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Hashtable parsetable, String connectionString, Boolean buildChain, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean firstKey)

   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean useOdbcRules)

   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString..ctor(String connectionString)

   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnectionOptions(String connectionString, DbConnectionOptions previous)

   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnectionPoolGroup(String connectionString, DbConnectionPoolGroupOptions poolOptions, DbConnectionOptions& userConnectionOptions)

   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ConnectionString_Set(String value)

   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.set_ConnectionString(String value)

   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Initialize(IDataServices dataServices, Object connection)

   at System.Data.Linq.DataContext.Init(Object connection, MappingSource mapping)

   at System.Data.Linq.DataContext..ctor(String fileOrServerOrConnection, MappingSource mapping)

   at Amanager2.LinQDataContext..ctor(String connection)

   at Amanager2.STATICS..cctor()

   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

   at Amanager2.UserControls.ucAtmsEditor..ctor()

   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandle& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)

   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean fillCache)

   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean fillCache)

   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)

   at System.Windows.Markup.BamlRecordReader.CreateInstanceFromType(Type type, Int16 typeId, Boolean throwOnFail)

   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

   at System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException.ThrowException(String message, Exception innerException, Int32 lineNumber, Int32 linePosition, Uri baseUri, XamlObjectIds currentXamlObjectIds, XamlObjectIds contextXamlObjectIds, Type objectType)

   at System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException.ThrowException(ParserContext parserContext, Int32 lineNumber, Int32 linePosition, String message, Exception innerException)

   at System.Windows.Markup.BamlRecordReader.ThrowExceptionWithLine(String message, Exception innerException)

   at System.Windows.Markup.BamlRecordReader.CreateInstanceFromType(Type type, Int16 typeId, Boolean throwOnFail)

   at System.Windows.Markup.BamlRecordReader.GetElementAndFlags(BamlElementStartRecord bamlElementStartRecord, Object& element, ReaderFlags& flags, Type& delayCreatedType, Int16& delayCreatedTypeId)

   at System.Windows.Markup.BamlRecordReader.BaseReadElementStartRecord(BamlElementStartRecord bamlElementRecord)

   at System.Windows.Markup.BamlRecordReader.ReadElementStartRecord(BamlElementStartRecord bamlElementRecord)

   at System.Windows.Markup.BamlRecordReader.ReadRecord(BamlRecord bamlRecord)

   at System.Windows.Markup.BamlRecordReader.Read(Boolean singleRecord)

   at System.Windows.Markup.TreeBuilderBamlTranslator.ParseFragment()

   at System.Windows.Markup.TreeBuilder.Parse()

   at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(Stream stream, ParserContext parserContext, Object parent, Boolean closeStream)

   at System.Windows.Application.LoadBamlStreamWithSyncInfo(Stream stream, ParserContext pc)

   at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Uri resourceLocator, Boolean bSkipJournaledProperties)

   at System.Windows.Application.DoStartup()

   at System.Windows.Application.<.ctor>b__0(Object unused)

   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter)

   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter, Delegate catchHandler)

   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WrappedInvoke(Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter, Delegate catchHandler)

   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()

   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(Object state)

   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData)

   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)

   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)

   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)

   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()

   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()

   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)

   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)

   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)

   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter)

   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter, Delegate catchHandler)

   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WrappedInvoke(Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter, Delegate catchHandler)

   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter)

   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority priority, Delegate method, Object arg)

   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)

   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)

   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)

   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)

   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()

   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)

   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)

   at System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)

   at System.Windows.Application.Run()

   at Amanager2.App.Main()
```

Comment: Please take a moment to properly format your question and to apply basic rules of grammar and capitalization

Answer (score 0):

The error is " System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'applicationintent'."
Googling that makes it look like a problem with a connection string.

From here...
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mdegre/2013/03/20/keyword-not-supported-applicationintent/

Resolution: You have to install the update that introduces support for the AlwaysOn features from SQL Server 2012

Does that sound feasible in your scenario?

Answer (score 0):

i change Connection string from

> Data Source=******;Initial Catalog=AmanagerDB2;Integrated Security=False;User ID=APP;Password=***;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=True

to

> Data Source=******;Initial Catalog=AmanagerDB2;User ID=APP;Password=***;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True

and all things be OK!